# Simulating Navigation Behaviors for a Quadruped Robot Using a Simpler Robot Model (TurtleBot) in Gazebo and RViz

Tags: ros2, slam, turtlebot, nav2

I am working on a project in ros2 humble involving a real-life quadruped robot (wavego with lidar), and I am exploring the feasibility of initially simulating navigation behaviors using a simpler robot model like TurtleBot in Gazebo and RViz. My goal is to develop and fine-tune navigation strategies with slam_toolbox and nav2 in simulation and transfer the movement commands to the real quadruped robot. Is it advisable to use a simpler robot model like TurtleBot for navigation simulations in Gazebo before deploying the learned behaviors on a quadruped robot?